# How To get the first time that a date is appear in a column?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new in JavaScript and in Google Speardsheet, And I need some help.
I have a table in google speardsheet, and in Column L - I have dates.
The table is sort by date, from the oldest to newst.

Now, I need 2 functions - 
The first - that will return me the last (=newest) date that exist in the table.
The second - that will return me the FIRST ROW that the newest date appear in the table.

I succeeded to write the first function(called: FindLastDate), but I have problem with the second one.
Please see my code and give your advice:

```
   function TheFirstRowWithThisDate() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var i = 0;
    var a = 0;
    d = FindLastDate();
    while (a==0) {
    if  (dataRange[d][11]==dataRange[i][11])
    { var a=i
    }
    i=i+1;
    }
    return a 
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need these as GAS functions? native functions in the spreadsheet will do this, =MAX(L:L) for latest date and =MATCH(MAX(L:L),L:L,0) for row number

Answer (score 0):

Dates are tricky to handle because of many reasons - the formatting of the spreadsheet cells, the time zone of the spreadsheet and the script all play a part.

So, given your requirement, I'd parse the date the hard way.

```
function TheFirstRowWithThisDate() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var d = FindLastDate(); 
  var lastDate = new Date(d); 
  for( var i = 0 ; i < dataRange.length ; i++){
    var tempDate = new Date(dataRange[i][11]); // Col L
    if(tempDate.getDate() == lastDate.getDate() && 
       tempDate.getMonth() == lastDate.getMonth() && 
       tempDate.getFullYear() == lastDate.getFullYear() ) { 
         return (i+1); // Return the row number which is 1 more than the index 
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```